# How to upload file to jenkins and use it for build?

Tags: curl, jenkins

I am very new to Jenkins, and I have been trying to use curl to build my job. Along with this curl I want to send a file to Jenkins which should be placed in particular directory of my workspace. I have been googling alot, but could not seem to find clear documentation that could lead me to solution. Please Guide. I looked at some other articles on Google and StackOverflow as well, but couldn't find what I am looking for.

> curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
>     --form file0=/home/abc.xml \
>     --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"/workspace", "file":"file0"}]}'

I tried this as well, didn't seem to work.

Comment: what is not working? what error you get? Jenkins saves the file to WORKSPACE ; you need to copy it.

Comment: Actually I couldn't find the file in workspace,  So  I can't figure out if it did upload or not! Also, is "name":"/workspace", correct? Do i need to configure my job to take a file parameter ? I've done that already, I've put location /workspace as file location in file parameter in config.

Comment: curl -X POST url/jobname/build    --form file0=sample.xml -F json='{"parameter": [{"name":"sample.xml", "file":"file0"}]}'  Gets me a null pointer exception

Comment: what is the file parameter name? that must be specified {"name":"NAME OF PARAMETER",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything Jayan said is correct. I am just making it more simple, for beginners like me. 
**Remember:**
@ sign is very important here in our curl url. Also, YOUR_JOBS_FILE_ARGUMENT_NAME is path where you want to store the file, along with name and extension of file. If you put abcd.xml in file location of your file parameter it will save abcd.xml in root of your workspace, if you want to put it in a folder xyz, you should write file location to be xyz/abcd.xml in your Filelocation of file parameter when you configure your job on jenkins and also make sure to use same in curl. So if you want to put abc.xml to xyz/abcd.xml on jenkins, please use command as :

> ```
> curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \ 
>   --form file0=@/home/abc.xml \ 
>   --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"xyz/abcd.xml", "file":"file0"}]}'
> ```

This is very basic stuff, but that is where I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 4):

From Jenkins file parameter help

> Specifies the location, relative in the workspace, where the uploaded
>   file will be placed (for example, like "jaxb-ri/data.zip")

The uploaded file location is relative to workspace.  **You need to copy/move it in a script.** The name portion is job's file argument's name. It is not name of your file

Here is from script.  The job has a file parameter named RECORDS_LIST.

```
curl -X POST  http://localhost:8080/job/builder/build \
             --form attachedfile=@c:/1.txt \
             --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"RECORDS_LIST", "file":"attachedfile"}]}'
```

Yours could be

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \ 
  --form file0=/home/abc.xml \ 
  --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"YOUR_JOBS_FILE_ARGUMENT_NAME", "file":"file0"}]}'
```

Please note that jenkins [command line api](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) can handle file upload

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ build builder \
      -p YOUR_JOBS_FILE_ARGUMENT_NAME=/home/abc.xml
```

[edit after seeing OP's own answer]

**Alert**

The filename path part in curl command has '@' (note that @ before path) . The jenkins cli does not need it.  This error, when happens, is  difficult to track.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understood most of it, except YOUR_JOBS_FILE_ARGUMENT_NAME. Let me explain what I understood, when I open jenkins and configure job to take parameters, I choose file parameter and give it a file location and description,so file location is that what you mean by YOUR_JOBS_FILE_ARGUMENT_NAME? and what could be the reason I get Null pointer exception when I followed above command, as you specified? I am sorry, I am asking very basic questions, but Jenkins is something I touched for the first time in my life yesterday. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: as you see, Jenkins cli is much more intuitive.

Comment: It is intuitive but I am looking for keeping lower dependencies in my project, so we are going with curl :)

Comment: Is it possible to update the build parameters remotely? using curl or any api?