# jenkins upload file - crumb error

Tags: html, jenkins, automation

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215249/how-to-upload-file-to-jenkins-and-use-it-for-build) question for uploading a file to jenkins server. I used the following command

```
curl -X POST  --user mohammed.s:56e253b01ae6928adc78aa8a21573884 http://localhost:8080/job/tarball_build/build --form attachedfile=@/home/shafeeque/test --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"abc", "file":"attachedfile"}]}'
```

But I am getting the following error. I searched a lot in internet, but none of answer worked for me. Can any one help me to point out if any error?

The error that I am getting is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /job/tarball_build/build. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69186246/374133